# AWS S3 Error Signature Does Not Match Javascript

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, signature

I am getting a "Signature Does Not Match" 403 error whenever I try to list objects from my bucket (or any call). **I can't use the SDK**, but I checked the XMLHttpRequest object in the SDK call to try and set up my own while also following the docs. I'm pretty sure my canonString is what is wrong, but I'm not sure exactly what is wrong with it. I checked my getSigningKey function with the values AWS provides and it computed it correctly so I know it isn't that. I'm also pretty sure the time is formatted properly (ends up being 20181002THHMMSSZ which I believe is correct) so I don't think it is that either. I just started reading about the string constand "UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD" for the x-amz-content-sha256, however replacing CryptoJS.SHA256("").getString() with "UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD" did not work!

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
var signingKey = getSigningKey(dateStamp, secretKey, regionName, serviceName);
var time = new Date();

time = time.toISOString();
time = time.replace(/:/g, '').replace(/-/g,'');
time = time.substring(0,time.indexOf('.'))+"Z";
console.log(time); //If it is October 2nd 2018 @4:16:38 (EST) it returns 20181002T201638Z

var canonString = "GET\n"+
                    encodeURI("/")+"\n"+
                    encodeURI("delimiter")+'='+encodeURI("/")+'&'+
                    encodeURI("max-keys")+'='+encodeURI("100")+'&'+
                    encodeURI("prefix")+'='+encodeURI("08")+'\n'+
                    "host:"+bucketName+".s3.amazonaws.com\n"+
                    'x-amz-content-sha256:'+CryptoJS.SHA256("").toString()+'\n'+
                    'x-amz-date:'+time+'\n'+
                    CryptoJS.SHA256("").toString();

var stringToSign = "AWS4-HMAC-SHA256\n"+
                    time+"\n"+
                    "20181002/us-east-1/s3/aws4_request\n"+
                    CryptoJS.SHA256(canonString).toString();

var authString = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(signingKey, stringToSign).toString();

request.open("GET", "https://"+bucketName+".s3.amazonaws.com/?delimiter=%2F&max-keys=100&prefix=08", false);
request.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential="+accessKey+"/20181002/us-east-1/s3/aws4_request, SignedHeaders=host;x-amz-content-sha256;x-amz-date, Signature="+authString);
request.setRequestHeader("host", bucketName+".s3.amazonaws.com");
request.setRequestHeader("x-amz-content-sha256", CryptoJS.SHA256("").toString());
request.setRequestHeader("x-amz-date", time);
console.log(request);
request.send();
```

That code produces this error message in response back:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>↵<Error><Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code><Message>The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.</Message><AWSAccessKeyId>{Access Key Hidden}</AWSAccessKeyId><StringToSign>AWS4-HMAC-SHA256↵20181002T192135Z↵20181002/us-east-1/s3/aws4_request↵514a2938b1655dd64c17a1ee5cdc3e5c31951f1532698a936e2228c075e6bc3d</StringToSign><SignatureProvided>6d685e715760ec0fd4c4665b10d7902902493df4e6252e6a6687752a5831d23d</SignatureProvided><StringToSignBytes>41 57 53 34 2d 48 4d 41 43 2d 53 48 41 32 35 36 0a 32 30 31 38 31 30 30 32 54 31 39 32 31 33 35 5a 0a 32 30 31 38 31 30 30 32 2f 75 73 2d 65 61 73 74 2d 31 2f 73 33 2f 61 77 73 34 5f 72 65 71 75 65 73 74 0a 35 31 34 61 32 39 33 38 62 31 36 35 35 64 64 36 34 63 31 37 61 31 65 65 35 63 64 63 33 65 35 63 33 31 39 35 31 66 31 35 33 32 36 39 38 61 39 33 36 65 32 32 32 38 63 30 37 35 65 36 62 63 33 64</StringToSignBytes><CanonicalRequest>GET↵/↵delimiter=%2F&amp;max-keys=100&amp;prefix=08↵host:{bucketName}.s3.amazonaws.com↵x-amz-content-sha256:e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855↵x-amz-date:20181002T192135Z↵↵host;x-amz-content-sha256;x-amz-date↵e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855</CanonicalRequest><CanonicalRequestBytes>47 45 54 0a 2f 0a 64 65 6c 69 6d 69 74 65 72 3d 25 32 46 26 6d 61 78 2d 6b 65 79 73 3d 31 30 30 26 70 72 65 66 69 78 3d 30 38 0a 68 6f 73 74 3a 64 65 6d 6f 61 70 70 2d 62 75 63 6b 65 74 2e 73 33 2e 61 6d 61 7a 6f 6e 61 77 73 2e 63 6f 6d 0a 78 2d 61 6d 7a 2d 63 6f 6e 74 65 6e 74 2d 73 68 61 32 35 36 3a 65 33 62 30 63 34 34 32 39 38 66 63 31 63 31 34 39 61 66 62 66 34 63 38 39 39 36 66 62 39 32 34 32 37 61 65 34 31 65 34 36 34 39 62 39 33 34 63 61 34 39 35 39 39 31 62 37 38 35 32 62 38 35 35 0a 78 2d 61 6d 7a 2d 64 61 74 65 3a 32 30 31 38 31 30 30 32 54 31 39 32 31 33 35 5a 0a 0a 68 6f 73 74 3b 78 2d 61 6d 7a 2d 63 6f 6e 74 65 6e 74 2d 73 68 61 32 35 36 3b 78 2d 61 6d 7a 2d 64 61 74 65 0a 65 33 62 30 63 34 34 32 39 38 66 63 31 63 31 34 39 61 66 62 66 34 63 38 39 39 36 66 62 39 32 34 32 37 61 65 34 31 65 34 36 34 39 62 39 33 34 63 61 34 39 35 39 39 31 62 37 38 35 32 62 38 35 35</CanonicalRequestBytes><RequestId>3F949681DE5F906A</RequestId><HostId>PPpPc2z8fL+UYQ1Qfo+CeH2z/Cf7sHRWJARYtLaw5+1LVYphP0jIhTtoEDjTipt3veaSd8/jvpY=</HostId></Error>"
```

edit: Forgot to include this error too:

```
Refused to set unsafe header "host"
```

Comment: This is a popular question at stackoverflow (at least 10x). I'd review those questions to see if any of the answers help you.

Comment: Also, there are numerous code samples in node.js on the Internet. Why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: I am have gone back into AWS docs and found some examples and tried calcing those signatures. My canonical string ends up being correct (not in the code I provided, I believe that incorrect - I get the right SHA256 value when I do the examples), but my stringToSign ends up being wrong in every example I try! However, I know my signing key function works because it worked correctly on a different example. Any idea what that happens? Furthermore, Host is a forbidden header like I thought, so how do they end up setting it? I'm very confused on how that works.